# How to install .Net Programmability support for Office 365 ProPlus?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

I installed Office 2013 from portal.office.com of my company account.

But as Office 365 installation is via One-click that there is no option to install .Net Programmability support.

Is there any way to install .Net Programmability support for Office 365?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a method for doing this.  Even the Office Deployment tool used for offline installation do not offer the options to deploy it.

The problem now is that Microsoft has been removing all the MSI (rational installer) based Office executables.  You won't find these anywhere unless you have a TechNet or MSDN subscriptions (I'm not sure if they are available from VLA portals).  The trial installation seems to still be available and you can sign in and activate them via your O365 logon.

I would suggest uninstalling the click-to-run version and then downloading the trial and install it the old fashioned way.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-office-professional-plus-2013

You will be asked to activate it and can select your organizational account. Using this method you should be able to restore ".Net Programmability support."

Answer (score 0):

The error message:

.NET Programmability Support for Microsoft Office is required to install Microsoft Mathematics Add-in

Here's what fixed it for me:

I had to make sure a specific version of .NET framework was enabled.

Make sure .NET 3.5 is enabled. 
 How to do it: (I'm using windows 8 and office 2013)
   - Control panel
     - Programs and features
       - Turn windows features on or off
           - Enable .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .net 2.0 and 3.0)

OK. That's the good news.

Bad news is that the add-in is very buggy. It may not have been properly tested with Windows 8 or onenote 2013.

Once the feature is installed, it appears to have focus and/or lockup issues in OneNote.
  So far the bug seems to be avoidable if you disable the   "send to one note" app in the system tray. (close/exit)
  Also, when graphing an equation you need to select the text box and not leave the caret blinking before clicking the graph button. This seems to avoid the focus and lock-up issues.